# Shorter linq query for finding currency symbol?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was asked to find what currency symbol does `USD`  (etc) has. (`$`)

another example :

`ILS` =>  `₪`

So I wrote this :

```
  var isoCurrency = "ILS".ToUpper().Trim();
 foreach(CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))
 {
     RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
     if(myRI1.ISOCurrencySymbol == isoCurrency)
     {
         NumberFormatInfo nfi = ci.NumberFormat;
        console.Write( nfi);
     }
 }
```

But it looks ugly.

So I converted it to linq :

```
var t= CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
       .Select(d=>new RegionInfo(d.LCID))
       .Where (f=>f.ISOCurrencySymbol=="ILS" )
       .Select(f=>f.CurrencySymbol).First();
```

But I believe I could make it shorter. ( 2 select's???)

any help ? (*assuming  this is the correct solution...*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `Select` seems redundant. You should generally filter first (using `Where`) then `Select`.

EDIT: Doh - I missed the `new RegionInfo()`. What about:

```
var ccy = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
              .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
              .First(ri => ri.ISOCurrencySymbol == "ILS").CurrencySymbol;
```

That assumes you know you are dealing with a valid `ISOCurrencySymbol`. If you can't make that assumption then use `FirstOrDefault` and check the result for `null` first before accessing the `CurrencySymbol`.

One additional point to note is that if you are performing this query frequently you could cache the result of `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures))`, although this really is a micro optimisation.

Comment: I need RegionInfo .... it produces the f which later i can take ISOCurrencySymbol From)

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloaded [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) method which accepts predicate (to combine `Where` and `First`)

```
 CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
            .First(r => r.ISOCurrencySymbol == "ILS")
            .CurrencySymbol;
```

This code does exactly what your code does. But actually you should use `FirstOrDefault` and try to get region for your ISO currency symbol. If region is found, then use it:

```
var isoCurrency = "ILS"
var region =  CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                        .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.ISOCurrencySymbol == isoCurrency);
if (region != null)
    // get region.CurrencySymbol
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
  var t = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                     .Select(d => new RegionInfo(d.LCID))
                     .First(f => f.ISOCurrencySymbol == "ILS").CurrencySymbol;
```